# Codeigniter 3 application: update MySQL table column and the corresponding view through Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

I am working on a **Register and Login** application with CodeIgniter 3 and Twitter Bootstrap.

I have a "users" MySQL table and a corresponding "users.php" view that renders the "users" table in an HTML format, like the image below illustrates:

[image]

The "Actions" column in the Bootstrap table has, on each row, an "Enable"  or "Disable" button, depending on the *state* of he user. The code for this part of the view is:

```
// Status column
<td>
   <?php if ($user->active == 1) {
    echo '<span class="text-success">' . 'Enabled' . '</span>';
    } else {
    echo '<span class="text-danger">' . 'Disabled' . '</span>';
    }
   ?>
</td>

// Enable/Disable buttons
<?php if ($user->active == 1) { ?>
    <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>users/deactivate/<?php echo $user->id ?>" title="Deactivate" class="btn btn-success btn-xs state-change" data-role="deactivate" data-id="<?php echo $user->id ?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></span> Disable</a>
<?php } else { ?>
   <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>users/activate/<?php echo $user->id ?>" title="Activate" class="btn btn-success btn-xs state-change" data-role="activate" data-id="<?php echo $user->id ?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> Enable</a>
<?php } ?>
```

I activate/deactivate users without page refresh, via AJAX:

```
$('.state-change').on('click', function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    var role = $(this).data('role');
    if (role == "activate") {
        var stateUrl = 'users/activate/';
    } else {
        var stateUrl = 'users/deactivate/';
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: stateUrl + id,
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'php',
        success: function(){
            console.log(id);
            console.log(role);
        }
    });
});
```

The problem is that the data regarding the state of the user does not come back to the view and the columns "Status" and "Actions" do not render correctly.

I wish I didn't have to update the view "statically" from the success callback, with jQuery's `html()` method or something similar.

```
function(){
    console.log(id);
    console.log(role);
    //change columns html here
}
```

What shall I do to update the view "dynamically"?

Comment: Why wouldn't you have to use html or something similar in the success callback? Ajax is just doing one thing to send and receive data, it's not reloading the page... The only way you can get the server side script of user active to trigger is if you reload the page. That being said, you can reload a div or a particular element but that in my opinion negates the efficacy of using Ajax in the first place as you are getting the whole page as a response and jquery is just picking out the updated div. For that there are plenty of resources on stack just search for jquery Ajax reload div.

Comment: FYI I have a similar system and do something like: https://pastebin.com/n8JXsLsf

Comment: most likely you will need a relative url like: `/'users/activate` also in your ajax success function you dont get any "feedback" from the controller `/'users/activate`. It would be great, if you could add the controller to the post...

Comment: You should blank out other peoples email address when on image when post on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use javascript to modify your table after you get the data back. Since you're already using jQuery, you have tools to make that pretty simple.

Your problem can be broken into two steps: Identify the right part of the page to update, and then modify the cells of interest.

Identifying the right cells is simplified because the mouse event passed to your function includes a reference to the thing that was clicked.

To make finding the right parts of the table easier, it's good to give each `<td>` a class:

```
// Status column
<td class="status-column">
    // your php status stuff from above
</td>

// Button column
<td class="activate-column">
    // your php button-drawing stuff from above
</td>
```

Now it will be easy to find what you're looking for to modify.

Here's your ajax call with a few additions to redraw the cells in question:

```
$('.state-change').on('click', function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    var role = $(this).data('role');
    if (role == "activate") {
        var stateUrl = 'users/activate/';
    } else {
        var stateUrl = 'users/deactivate/';
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: stateUrl + id,
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'php',
        success: function(){
            console.log(id);
            console.log(role);

            // find the row that is the parent of the clicked button - http://api.jquery.com/parent/
            var row = evt.target.parent('tr');

            // use the class of the table cell to identify it. http://api.jquery.com/find/
            var statusCell = row.find('.status-column').first();

            // now put in the new status. http://api.jquery.com/html/
            if (role == "activate") {
                statusCell.html('<span class="text-success">Enabled</span>');
            } else {
                statusCell.html('<span class="text-danger">Disabled</span>');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I'll leave the button column for you to practice with :).

Edit: you can also manipulate the DOM with non-jQuery methods that are perhaps more to your liking. This is what jQuery is doing under the hood anyway.

You can read more about them [at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model).

```
// build the new DOM node
var newStatusCellContent = document.createElement('span');
newStatusCellContent.setAttribute('class', role == 'activate' ? 'text-enabled' : 'text-danger');
newStatusCellContent.textContent = role == 'activate' ? 'Enabled' : 'Disabled';

// get the parent <td> node from the jQuery object
var statusCell = row.find('.status-column').get(0);

// swap the old contents for the new
var oldChild = statusCell.childNodes[0]
statusCell.replaceNode(newStatusCellContent, oldChild);
```

Careful study of the documentation at the above link will probably reveal ways to make that more efficient for your particular case. Keep in mind that this is the same thing the jQuery `html()` method does — or Angular or any other — and that while it keeps you away from HTML, it doesn't really improve your code in this case. I really hate HTML, but it's the tool we're given.

Note that php also has DOM libraries; if you wanted, you could use those to build your original page as well, and be done with HTML forever. But I don't recommend it except in certain cases.

Comment: It looks great but, as I have mentioned, `statusCell.html('<span class="text-success">Enabled</span>');` is what I wish to avoid. Would using AngularJS instead of AJAX be a good idea?

Comment: Each table row has an id attribute equal to the id of the user.

Comment: I guess the key is: why don't you want to use this method? Angular, when you strip away the difference in syntax, will do the same thing. You have a choice: modify the page, or reload it. In this case, modifying the page is a better choice.

Comment: Note that I have added code for using native javascript rather than jQuery, which builds the new DOM objects in an object-oriented way.

Comment: What is the point of `var statusCell = row.find('.status-column').first();`? What does it do?

Comment: The first thing to do is read the documentation (I put the link in a comment in the code), but what `find()` does is start with the jQuery object for the row and then search through all its children (which includes the cells in that row and whatever is in those cells), and returns all items with a class "status-column". Since that method can match more than one thing, it returns a list. We know that there will only be one cell in that row that matches that selector, so we just use the `first()` method to get the first one.

Answer (score 1):

The above answers are adequate - you must use JavaScript given your scenario. It seems the trouble lies in making the leap from dynamic web pages  to dynamic HTML.

Read the last line of the summary here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_HTML